# Why don't some of my push storyboard segues show an option for peek and pop?

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard, 3dtouch, peek-pop

Some of my push segues show an option for peek & pop while other push segues don't show the option. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found out why? I can't see the option on any segue =(

Comment: @Robertibiris Nope, but if you are having the same issue an up vote would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sorry about the late Reply. I was having the same problem. it seems like by design Apple only show the peek&pop option in interface builder for Action segues (like segues from buttons or cells to a UIViewController) but NOT for Manual segues (i.e segues from ViewController to ViewController, that we usually trigger by code and set-up in prepareForSegue: ). This is mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/Add3DSegue.html)